# Jmeter Parsing specific id in another request

Tags: testing, jmeter

I need to fetch id parameter from JSON and parse that id value in another request URL. Issue is in JSON i am getting multiple values of id like 6, Etc/UTC etc. I want only integer value to pass.
Please suggest solution for automate this instead of passing value everytime. [image: Screenshot of json extractor response]

Comment: What you have tried so far? Show us the code.

Comment: I have tried most of the syntax available online but unable to read int value and pass them to another api url. I am new to jmeter.

Answer (score 0):

You can [add regex expression](https://octoperf.com/blog/2017/03/09/how-to-extract-data-from-json-response-using-jmeter/) to you JSON expression

> $..book[?(@.author =~ /.*REES/i)]  All books matching regex (ignore case)

In your case add regular expression for numbers:

```
=~ /.*(\d+)/i)]
```

Comment: i have use JSON extractor instead.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you need to amend your [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) query to fetch not all IDs but only the ID(s) which is(are) numeric. Unfortunately without seeing your response and JSON Path query we cannot suggest anything meaningful.

Looking into your response I can only suggest only getting the first numeric ID using [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black).

1. Add JSR223 PostProcessor **after** the JSON Extractor
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   for (int i = 1; i <= (vars.get('id_matchNr') as int); i++) {
       def currentVar = vars.get('id_' + i)
       if (currentVar =~ '(\\d+)') {
           vars.put('someid', currentVar)
           break;
       }
   }
   ```
3. You will be able to access the first numeric ID as `${someid}` where required.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for help.
JSON path query- /api/v1/node/pool/${someid}/bid
Response- PFA
I am able to get the id from response as per solution suggested by you but need to pass all the ids one by one that are extracted from JSON extractor. Can you please guide.